# Unity Build Error : ('Assets/Plugins/UnityPurchasing/Bin/Stores.dll') : the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, build, in-app-purchase

I am trying to build an **APK (for Android)** in Unity 2017, but get a strange build error.

Here are what I have done:

(1) I have already imported Unity IAP, and have verified that the lib Store.dll actually exists inside the folder  **"Assets/Plugins/UnityPurchasing/Bin/Stores.dll"**

(2) I have changed the *Build Settings > Player Settings > API Compatibility Level* to **Net 2.0**.

However, I still have this build error:

**ArgumentException: The Assembly UnityEngine.Purchasing is referenced by Stores ('Assets/Plugins/UnityPurchasing/Bin/Stores.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 cache, BuildTarget target) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:156)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[] paths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, BuildTarget target) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:196)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)**

Please let me know how to fix this build error.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue.

Basically, I need to **ENABLE** the IAP purchase option as follow: **Go to the Unity menu bar -> Click on Window -> Services -> In App Purchase -> Enable**.

After that, the build works fine.

--

PS: I was switching projects a few times and forgot to re-enable the IAP in the new project. That was the reason for this bug to show up.